# What is the meaning of >>= in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

What is the meaning of the `>>=` symbol in C or C++?  Does it have any particular name?

I have this `for` loop in some CUDA code which looks like this

```
for(int offset=blockDim.x; offset>0; offset >>=1)
{
   //Some code 
}
```

How does the offset variable get modfied with the `>>=` operator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `>>=` symbol is the assignment form of right-shift, that is `x >>= y;` is short for `x = x >> y;` (unless overloaded to mean something different).

Right shifting by 1 is equivalent to divide by 2. That code looks like someone doesn't trust the compiler to do the most basic optimizations, and should be equivalent to:

```
for( int offset = blockDim.x; offset > 0; offset /= 2 ){ ... }
```

More information about bitwise operations here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_shift#Bit_shifts

Comment: Given that in this case both operands are of type int, use of an overloaded operator can be excluded.

Comment: Right shifting by 1 is very similar to dividing by 2, but you can get a slightly different result for a negative number because of the rounding rules for integer division.  In this example, there are no negative numbers, so here it is equivalent.  But, in C and C++, -3/2 == -1 while -3>>1 = -2.

Answer (score 1):

Literally `offset = offset >> 1`, that is, `offset` divided by 2

Answer (score 1):

That's the assignment version of right shift:

```
foo >>= 2; // shift the bits of foo right by two places and assign the result to foo
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a bitwise shift right operator. it shifts the bits of the variable to right by the value of right operand.