# What does this '>>=' mean?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

While reading a 'C' code I came across this line of code

```
b>>=1;
```

Can anyone clarify what does this mean?

Comment: It's the same thing as `b = b >> 1`.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking because it's trivial knowledge.

Comment: `b = b >> n` is equivalent to `b = b / pow(2, n)`

Comment: It's not unclear at all, nor is it non-reproducible. This is a very trivial question but not *incorrect* in any way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057260/meaning-of-in-a-c-c-code

Comment: Actually, just typing ">>=" in the search box would have provided a wealth of material.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus it's not true for negative integer values of `b`.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience everyone, I wasn't able to search for it through google I tried searching the operator in google but wasn't of any use and couldn't get anything related to it.

Comment: I agree with @Puppy: the reason provided for closing this question is completely wrong. Nevertheless, the question itself is terrible: simply looking up C operators would have quickly provided an answer, quite possibly with less work than posting the question here.

Comment: @TedHopp it's part of Stackoverflow strategy to discourage closing very basic questions with no minimal research effort: they removed reasons for bad questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057260/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-c-or-c

Comment: _duplicate_ of [What is the meaning of >>= in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057260/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 4):

This expression based on operator >>= known as a compound assignment operator

```
b>>=1;
```

is equivalent to

```
b = b >> 1;
```

b >> 1 shift right one poistion the value stored in b provided that the operator is not a iser-defined operator. 
For example if b has the following internal representation (let's assume that b has type unsigned char)

```
00001111
```

then b >> 1 results in

```
00000111
```

b shall have an integral type. If b is negative then the result is implementation defined.
As I have already mentioned you may overload this operator for user-defined types.

In fact expression `b >> 1` is equivalent to `b / 2` As you can see the example above the original value `00001111` is equal to 15 in the decimal notation while the result value `00000111` is equal to 7 in the decimal notation. The same result you could get using expression `b / 2`

Thus

```
b >>= 1;
```

can be written also as

```
b /= 2;
```

Comment: mention (if it is the case) that this code is just like the code " a += 2"

Comment: @josinalvo  it is equivalent to b /= 2.

Answer (score 2):

Bitshift right `b` by one bit, then assign the result back to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

`>>=` is a *compound assignment* operator.

For compound assignment operators,

```
E1 op= E2
```

is equivalent to

```
E1 = E1 op (E2)
```

so `b >>= 1` is equivalent to `b = b >> 1`.

Comment: Typically, by convention, `@` is used to denote arbitrary operator.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm using here the same terminology used by the C Standard.

Answer (score 0):

`b>>=1` is a [Compound assignment Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf2hxf.aspx)

It expands to-

```
b = b >> 1;
```

It means you are right shifting `b` by one time and you are storing the result in `b`.

Right shifting is nothing but divided by 2. that is `b = b >> 1` equals to `b = b/2`

Comment: The only difference is that for negative integers, `b = b >> 1` will round down if there is a remainder, while `b = b/2` will round up towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is the right shift operator, meaning `b = b >> 1;`